# MimeMessage not parsing attachments in outlook EML files

Tags: outlook, jakarta-mail, eml

I'm parsing/extracting data from `eml` files using `javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage` .

```
 MultiPart multiPart = 
 (MultiPart)MimeMessage.getContent();
  ...//check if attachments are present, then extract it
 MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart)multiPart.getBodyPart(attachmentIndex);
 String fileName = part.getFileName();
```

The file name always prints null. How do I know the attachment filename and extension? Without at least knowing the extension, I can't even save the file properly.

Basically, I'm looking for a generic Java library API which parses `eml` files and gives message text and attachments (recursively?).

Answer (score 1):

Attachments aren't **required** to have a filename.

If your EML file is in MIME format and contains a file name, but JavaMail isn't finding it, post an example.

Comment: but in my case, a single EML file contains multiple attachments. Unless I know the file extension, how would I save the content in proper format?

Comment: How do I determine if my EML files are in MIME format? I see that before each binary content, there is `Content-Type: application/pdf; name=xyz.pdf` and `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=` are present.

Comment: Looks like it's MIME format.  What version of JavaMail are you using?  If you run the [JavaMail mgshow.java sample program](https://github.com/javaee/javamail/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/msgshow.java) on the EML file, what output do you get?

Comment: towards the end I get
`%%EOF`
`CONTENT-TYPE: application/vnd.ms-excel; `
`name="..."`
`FILENAME: ...xls`
`This is just an input stream`

after that some binary data on the output console in IDE.

Comment: Looks like JavaMail is finding the file name.  Look at the msgshow.java source code and figure out what it's doing differently than what your program is doing.